# Powershell - How to add Bulk Copy command in Transaction block

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy, powershell-5.0

I am using PowerShell version 5, I want to Add the BulkCopy command in the Transaction block, so that if at all there are any issues while copying data from 1 server to another, then nothing should be committed.

Below is my code, where Transaction works for other multiple SQL Commands (Create, Insert) so if anything fails while inserting table is also not created. But same is not working for the BulkCopy command.

Script

```
$SrcconnString = "Data Source=<Server-Name>;Database=<DB-Name>;User ID=<Login>;Password=<Pass>"
$TrgconnString = "Data Source=<Server-Name>;Database=<DB-Name>;User ID=<Login>;Password=<Pass>"

$error.clear()



$TrgTblName = 'dbo.test'
$BulkCopyTimeout = '1000'
$BulkCopyBatchSize = '20000'

Import-Module -Name SQLServer
write-host 'module loaded'

 #Create a SQL connection object
 
$Srcconn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $SrcconnString
$Trgconn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $TrgconnString


 #Attempt to open the connection
    $Srcconn.Open()
    $Trgconn.Open()
    
$tran = $Trgconn.BeginTransaction()
    
 try
{   
    
    if($Srcconn.State -eq "Open" -And $Trgconn.State -eq "Open" )
{
       Write-Host "connection successful"

  <# Below Commented block works for Transaction  #>
      
     <#
    $script = @"
            DROP Table IF EXISTS dbo.test_bulk;
            Create table dbo.test_bulk (Id int, Name varchar(2));
            INSERT INTO dbo.test_bulk(Id,name) Values (1,'vj'),(2,'jgjeguegjeg');
            
"@
     
      
       $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($script, $Trgconn)
        $cmd.Transaction = $tran
        [void]$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      
      $tran.Commit()
    #> 

    
      

         $sql = "SELECT top 100 * FROM dbo.test(NOLOCK)";
        
           $sqlCommand = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql, $Srcconn)
          [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader] $sqlReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()                        
          $bulkCopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($TrgconnString, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::KeepIdentity,$tran)
          $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $TrgTblName
          $bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeOut = $BulkCopyTimeout
          $bulkCopy.BatchSize = $BulkCopyBatchSize
          $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($sqlReader)
         

          $tran.Commit()
          $sqlReader.Close()
         $bulkCopy.Close()



      
      }
       
    }  
      catch
      {
      $tran.Rollback()
        #Write-Host "Operation failed"
        #$error
       $_.exception.message
      }
    
    finally
    {
    $Srcconn.Close()
    $Trgconn.Close()
    $error.clear()
    }
```

**Update:**
After @DanGuzman comment, I Specified the transaction object ($tran) as the third parameter for the SqlBulkCopy command,

```
 $bulkCopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($TrgconnString, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::KeepIdentity,$tran)
```

but now it fails with an error

```
Exception calling "WriteToServer" with "1" argument(s): "WriteToServer requires an open and available connection. The Connection's current state is closed."
```

Comment: `$tran.Commit()` after `$bulkCopy.Close()`?

Comment: Specify the transaction object as the third [`SqlBulkCopy` constructor argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#constructors) and commit/rollback as needed.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman but the example in the link is for C# and I am not very familiar with Powershell, so not sure what or where can I add argument? Can you please share an example.

Comment: @VikasJ, the constructor syntax is similar to C# or VB.NET. Specify the arguments in parenthesis like `$bulkCopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($TrgconnString, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::KeepIdentity, $tran)`.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes I just did that, but now I am getting error, please check my updated post.

Comment: @VikasJ, I didn't notice you were using a connection string instead of the connection. The overloaded constructor uses a connection object rather than connection string. Try `$bulkCopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($Trgconn, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::KeepIdentity, $tran)`

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you so much, I just had 1 question, as I had asked in my post, If there is any error while BulkCopy command is executed I don't want any row to be committed. But since we are processing data in batches, I am assuming will there be a separate transaction for each batch? so let's say if batch 1 was successful and batch 2 had some error, then I don't want even batch 1 to commit data into the database, instead it should be rollbacked and script should end right away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232041/discussion-between-vikas-j-and-dan-guzman).

Answer (score 0):

Search for bcp utility and try to use it

Answer (score 0):

I got similar setup working when passing the actual connection instead of connection string as the first parameter.

In your example it would be:

```
    $bulkCopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($Trgconn, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::KeepIdentity,$tran)
```